# Can someone explain to be the reason for this being put on-hold?

Tags: discussion

https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34263/how-are-contention-based-mac-protocols-classified

The stated reason is it's off-topic because it's about "education, certification, or homework". It's not a homework question nor an exam question. It *is* in preparation for an exam, where the notes are ambiguous. I've asked questions on NetworkEngineering and SO in relation to exam material before. I believe homework questions are banned on both sites. I've stated on multiple [questions](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9770/how-do-vlans-affect-the-broadcast-domain) that they are in relation to university material. I've never had an issue.

This is not a straight copy-and-paste homework question, so why is it closed?

Edit:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original post is gone, so I can't take a look. But I have to at least state that this seems like another case of a perfectly good question that mentioned a particular trigger word (education) and was therefore put on hold.

Of course there is no way to tell for sure without seeing the original post. But I do want to speak to this point made by Ron:

> The problem with those type of questions is that the course material may not agree with what happens in the real world

I'm of the mentality that this is not our problem. If an instructor or education curriculum teaches something that doesn't match up to reality, that is *their* problem, not ours. We should always (continue to) answer questions from the perspective of reality.

To that end, I don't believe we should exclude education questions. Maybe the obvious "copy paste do my homework for me", but well though out questions, or questions from a student asking for clarification or further understanding should be welcomed. They are, after all, network engineers in training.... who will become network engineers, and hopefully remember a good experience when they interacted with the Network Engineering Stack Exchange. AKA, they are the future posters and responders.

Comment: I've added my original question as an image in the question body. That's exactly it. If what's I'm being taught doesn't reflect reality, that is the fault of my lecturers and I can bring it up with them. If anything, being taught misleading information in university makings getting a proper answer to my question even more vital. As for the quality of my question, I thought it was acceptable. It's far from a copy-paste homework question which are understandably unacceptable. The rule shouldn't have been applied here.

Comment: Here are the comments for the question. http://i.imgur.com/TUZG2VN.png

Answer (score 0):

You wrote that this is for an exam revision, and that makes it an education question.

As it says in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Network Engineering Stack Exchange is for asking questions about
>   professionally managed networks in a business environment.

Also, under Off-Topic: "*education, certification, or homework*" questions.

The problem with those type of questions is that the course material may not agree with what happens in the real world, which is what we answer about here. Many such questions which have popped up here over the years have typos in either the question or answer, or someone's instructor was giving out information (which could be tested) that doesn't match the answers which would be given here.

The community has decided not to accept those types of questions. This has been the case from the very early days. See [this question](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42/certification-education-questions) and the accepted answer.

Comment: It should be noted that the link you provided where "the community" decided not to accept the type of questions is from April of 2014. And there have been more recent attempts by members of the community to relax this restriction.

Comment: There has yet to be a consensus to change the wording on that page. Currently, those types of questions are explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Is consensus what it would take? (this is a serious question). Or just majority?  Or... what would it take?

Comment: I will defer to @YLearn, as the last person to update the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page as to the details of what it takes to get that changed. I have seen no overwhelming desire of the community to change one of the founding precepts of this site. The community is certainly free to change its mind, but the (strong) desire of one or two people is not sufficient.